Creation of iteractive constraints to Cobyla
I am trying to make a set of constraints. I need build a trogonometric product where for each enter from a list i know if I use cos or sin.
def f(a, lista, limites, W, D, A):
    def g(x):
        rest=1
        for i in lista:
            if i==0:
                rest*= rest*np.cos(x[lista.index(i)])
            else:
                rest*= rest*np.sin(x[lista.index(i)])
        return (rest*W*D/(2*A[a]))-limites[a][0]
    return g

constr=[]
for t in range (2**carro.qubits):
     binario = [int(x) for x in f"{t:0{carro.qubits}b}"]
     constr.append({'type':'ineq', 'fun': f(t, binario, limites, carro.W, carro.D, pesos)})

I dont know what is wrong here
